# Multiple combo boxes in Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I need 3 combo boxes to autopopulate/autofill 1 textbox with data. I know how to accomplish this with 1 combo box autofilling 1 textbox, but how can I do it with 3. Would it be something like this? Need assistance.

```
Me.Textbox.Value = Me.Combobox1.Column(1) + Me.Combobox1.Column(2) + Me.Combobox1.Column(3)
```

Comment: What is the datatype you are adding together from the comboboxes? Strings? Integers?

Comment: I'm not trying to add data. Its a condition if those 3 combo boxes have data then it should auto fill a text box.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you can simply just add in this to each combo's `AfterUpdate` event:

```vb
Private Sub Combo1_AfterUpdate()

     If Nz(Me.Combo1.Column(1), "") <> "" And Nz(Me.Combo2.Column(2), "") <> "" And Nz(Me.Combo3.Column(3), "") <> "" Then
         Me.Text1.Value = Nz(Me.Combo1.Column(1), "") & " " & Nz(Me.Combo2.Column(2), "") & " " & Nz(Me.Combo3.Column(3), "")
     End If

End Sub
```

This part: `& " " &` is just to add a space between each value, remove it if you don't need it.  So in the `If` statement you are just checking to make sure all of the comboboxes have something selected before updating the textbox.